# Strange error message "inconsistent use of library definitions" in flowjs

Tags: flowtype

I have been using flowjs for a while and most error message are quite clear, but now I've got something like this:

```
src/framework/uitable/show.js:0
inconsistent use of library definitions
 46:    columns: Array<UiTableConfigColumnType>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with. See lib: src/framework/uitable/uitable.js.flow:46
 52: type UiTableDataColsType = Array<string>;
                                      ^^^^^^ string. See lib: src/framework/uitable/uitable.js.flow:52

src/framework/uitable/show.js:0
inconsistent use of library definitions
 52: type UiTableDataColsType = Array<string>;
                                      ^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with. See lib: src/framework/uitable/uitable.js.flow:52
 46:    columns: Array<UiTableConfigColumnType>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: src/framework/uitable/uitable.js.flow:46
```

and have no idea on what to look for.

The types in definition seem to be ok, they are not related to each other and the source points to line 0.

I have never seen this error before and I do not expect any help on tracking down the actual source of this error.

I just need some help in understanding what the error itself means and why flowjs reports the error `src/framework/uitable/show.js:0` at line 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## What does `inconsistent use of library definitions` mean?

Most Flow errors occur when type `A` flows to type `B`. For example, if you call a function that expects a parameter with type `B`, but you pass it something with type `A`. When this happens, Flow outputs an error about how type `A` is incompatible with type `B`.

Sometimes, you have code like

```
// in file foo.js
libraryCallB(libraryCallA());
```

In this case, maybe the return type of `libraryCallA()` doesn't match the parameter type of `libraryCallB()`. So Flow will emit an error that the types are incompatible. However, since both library calls are defined in a library (say `lib.js`), the error message wouldn't mention `foo.js` at all. This is not ideal, since the bug is probably in `foo.js:0`

So, as a bandaid, we just kind of stick `foo.js:0` at the top of the error as a hint. It means that we were typechecking `foo.js` when we noticed one library type flowing into an incompatible library type.

We've been trying to improve error messages, so these errors should be less prevalent. But they do still happen.

## What about your code?

- The error is likely somewhere in `src/framework/uitable/show.js`
- Try `flow check --traces 10` It runs a normal `flow check`, but saves these "traces", which are sort of like stack traces for Flow's internal type checking logic. The `10` means print traces up to depth 10. The output is hard to understand unless you are familiar with Flow's internals, but maybe it will mention the location in `src/framework/uitable/show.js` that is triggering the error.
- I'm guessing the error has to do with an `Array<string>` being used as an `Array<UiTableConfigColumnType>`, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Using `flow check --traces 10` I was now able to pin down the actual problem and as I believe that this is actually something that might need to be improved, I also created a stripped down example on how to reproduce this error and created a separate issue https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2673.